# Is there a color scheme designer like Kuler that can hold many colors (+30) at a time?

Tags: color, tools, adobe-kuler

I'm designing a color scheme for a web application with a data dashboard. I want the graphs and data visualizations to have a default color palette with distinct colors that maximize the ease of seeing relationships in the data. The app will display a very wide variety of data sets, many of which will require a large number of colors.

I'd like to pick at least 50 default colors. Is there any application like Kuler where you can see color swatches next to each other and you can also pick a lot of different colors? Kuler limits you to 5.

Comment: Colorschemer http://www.colorschemer.com/products.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the best tool I found: http://color.hailpixel.com/ It lets you look at an unlimited number of swatches next to each other.

You can enter in specific hex codes in the url and also re-arrange colors by re-arranging the hex codes in the url. You can also adjust RGB values within settings.

Also it's free.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a similar tool and found this: http://vrl.cs.brown.edu/color

It automatically generates palettes up to 20 colors and has some settings to fine-tune the palette features like "Perceptual Distance" between the colors, which are very useful.

I know it does not handle 50+ colors but I can't find anything better: what I'm personally doing to handle palettes this big is just repeat the colors starting from the twenty-first.